# Is it a good or a bad SEO practice to create a same URL with different directory?

Tags: seo, url, search-results

We have a website with many different modules. Currently we are trying to implement the **"Related Questions"** SERP Feature for our FAQs page.

**Eg:** There are two pages `example.com/xyzservice.htm` & `example.com/faq/xyzservice.htm`  in a different directory.

Content is unique, Meta Tags are unique, but Page URL's are the same.

Is this new faq page will be impacted upon the visibility of my service page with this structure?

Comment: What is the sense to make the same file name, if the content of both urls is unique?

Comment: "but Page URL's are the same" - in your example, the URLs are clearly different. It's just the last path segment (the _filename_) that are the same. I don't see how this is good or bad for SEO. The one within the `/faq` "directory" is presumably the FAQs for the `xyxservice`?

Comment: @MrWhite Exactly! & we are putting the same file name because we want to relate this faq page with it's related service page. Now the query is like that is it OK to doing so or my service page got affected by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this is affect to your SEO. It just treated it as a new page of yours. However, I think your user will be confused as your link was quite same to another.

As long as you said, content, meta, title etc are the same, it is ok for SEO.